# Cataloging Problematic Cells by Hyperlink Copying

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to flag problematic cells and link the cell hyperlink to another cell to review later. Here is my code. Not all of the code is visible. I Called "i" and "j" as long. The error occurs on `newLink = Range("AL" & i).Hyperlinks(1).Address` claiming that it is "out of range." I think this means that it is calling something that doesn't exist, but to be honest i'm not sure.

```
    If Range("AK" & i).Value = "On" Then
        If Range("AL" & i).Value = 0 And Range("AM" & i).Value = 0 Then
            Range("AL" & i, "AM" & i).Interior.ColorIndex = 6
            'Cells("AL" & i) = H.Address'
            ErrorCount = ErrorCount + 1
            Dim newLink As String 
            newLink = Range("AL" & i).Hyperlinks(1).Address 
            Range("IV" & j).Hyperlinks.Add anchor:=Range("IV" & j), Address:=Range("IV" & j) 
            Range("IV" & j).Hyperlinks(1).Address = newLink 
            j = j + 1
        End If
```

Comment: have you tried it without .address?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is no hyperlink attached to a cell then `Range("foo").Hyperlinks.Count` will return `0` and therefore you will get an 'Out of range' error.

You just need to wrap the `newLink = ...` statement in an `If` to check if there is already a hyperlink there. E.g.

```
If Range("AL" & i).Hyperlinks.Count = 1 Then
  newLink = Range("AL" & i).Hyperlinks(1).Address 
Else
  'what else will you do?
End If
```